# Automatically Inserting Into A Table View in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to insert data into a table view cell in Xcode automatically so that it grabs data from my Firestore database and inserts into the cells. I have two questions:

1) Is this possible, and if so, how would I do it?
2) If I wanted to use something like a listener, so it would update in realtime, how would I do this?

Thank you so much!

Comment: firebase or firestore? Did you look in to addSnapshotListener? there is a lot of material if you look that up

Comment: I am using the Cloud Firestore database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing for IOS 13+ you can try to use combine for that check this link:

http://trycombine.com/posts/combinedatasources-simple-static-list/

Also if there’s a framework called RxSwift that you can create reactive code based on incomes from Firebase real time data. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift